How do I submit a form with SquareUp and retrieve the token from JavaScript using Filament 3 with Livewire?
I've developed a custom page in Filament 3 and would like to utilize SquareUp to obtain the payment token, then submit the form upon successful retrieval and process the logic in save method.
Here's my form code
<x-filament-panels::form wire:submit='save' id="billing-form">
    {{ $this->form }}

        <script src="https://sandbox.web.squarecdn.com/v1/square.js"></script>

        <section>
            <div id="payment-form">
                <div id="payment-status-container"></div>
                <div id="card-container"></div>
                <button id="card-button" type="button">Pay</button>
            </div>
        </section>
</x-filament-panels::form>

Here's my javascript code in retrieving the token from squareup.
        <script type="module">
            const payments = Square.payments('{{$this->squareAppId}}', '{{$this->squareLocation}}');
            const card = await payments.card();
            await card.attach('#card-container');

            const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
            cardButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
                const statusContainer = document.getElementById('payment-status-container');
                const billingForm = document.getElementById('billing-form');

                try {
                    const result = await card.tokenize();
                    if (result.status === 'OK') {
                        console.log(`Payment token is ${result.token}`);
                        statusContainer.innerHTML = "Payment Successful";

                        // SUBMIT filament form
                    } else {
                        let errorMessage = `Tokenization failed with status: ${result.status}`;
                        if (result.errors) {
                            errorMessage += ` and errors: ${JSON.stringify(result.errors)}`;
                        }

                        throw new Error(errorMessage);
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                    statusContainer.innerHTML = "Payment Failed";
                }
            });
        </script>

